M2doc template for initializing a variable with specific UID?
I am new in M2DOC addon with capella, i would like to initialize a variable in a template with a specific UID of my model
what is the correponding line in the template?
regards
Laurent
the code is near from fromUID('') but i cannot get it in the documentation

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If You can write an expression in your template that use the variable, for instance:
{m:myUUID}

Then you can define its type by using the template properties wizard to set is type to String.
Lastly you will need to add a value to this variable in your .genconf using the generation configuration wizard.
If yous want to access the UUID of a CapellaElement, you can use the id EAtribute:
{m:myCapellaElement.id}


Hi Ivan, I want to use something like this :{m:let myvar = fromUID('xxxxxxxxx')} where 'xxxxxxxxx' is the UID of a specific object in my model

{m:let myvar = myCapellaElement.id} should work to get the UUID.

If you want the Object from its UUID you will need to create a Java service and use the Resource.getEObject() with the UUID.
